# I asked questions but they no more exsits under my account

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, user-accounts

I have wrote the following 2 questions :-

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146056/quick-edit-problem-if-i-modify-start-date-without-modifiying-end-date-inside

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146054/quick-edit-problem-on-people-or-group-field

but I found that the username for them have been changed to "user24275", and they no longer appear under my questions, actually all my questions have been removed !!! can anyone advice on the reason ?

Answer (score 3):

The account has been deleted for trying to bypass a moderator imposed suspension John.